Columns not equally spaced in tabular*
I am using \tabular* and my columns are not equally spaced. Also, the last column does not reach the border of the table. I don't want to use \multicolumn for all rows as it's so messy. But I had to use it in the first two rows as I needed merged cells, and I couldn't find any other way to do that. I need the table to automatically fit the overall content width of the pdf, and adjust columns by itself accordingly.
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[]
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l cccc @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{My model} 
\\  
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Model Specification }\\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c} {Fitted parameters}\\ \hline
& Estimate & Std. Error & t value & Pr(\textgreater{}$\mid t \mid$) \\ 

\midrule
$\omega_1$   & 11.523 & 9.6684 & 1.1918& 1.167e-01\\
{$\alpha_1$}  &0.009& 0.0017 &0.0076& 4.970e-02**\\
{$\gamma_1$} &0.932 & 0.5250 & 1.7756 &3.790e-02 **\\
{$\beta_1$} &0.386 &0.2238 &1.7266& 4.212e-02**\\
{$\omega_2$}& 1.486& 0.7199 &2.0636 &1.95e-02**\\
{$\alpha_2$}&0.001 &0.0016 &0.0055 &4.978e-02**\\
{$\gamma_2$}&0.323& 0.2087& 1.5480& 6.082e-02***\\
{$\beta_2$} &0.530& 0.1646 &3.2172 &6.472e-04 *\\
\bottomrule                  
      
\end{tabular*}
\caption{model}
    \label{tab:yr3tab2}
\medskip\footnotesize
Notes: *, **, and *** 
\end{minipage}

\end{table}
\end{document}


Are you using a two-column layout? Please confirm.

In my opinion, the main problem with this table isn't that the column widths differ quite a bit. Instead, it's the fact that the table doesn't fit inside the textblock (assuming your document employs a two-column layout). In turn, the main cause of the table not fitting is that some of the headers are quite long -- excessively long, actually.
The remedies? Either switch to a full-width table* environment and replace \columnwidth with \textwidth, or simplify and shorten the headers. I'd recommend doing the latter.
Since you're now using a table environment (unlike in one of your earlier postings), it's not necessary to employ a minipage environment. Finally, I'd replace the c column type with the S column type (provided by the siunitx package) in order to format the numbers in columns 2 thru 5.

\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
   >{$}l<{$} 
   S[table-format=2.3]
   S[table-format=1.4]
   S[table-format=1.4]
   S[table-format=1.3e-1,tight-spacing,
     table-space-text-post = {$^{***}$}] }
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{My model} \\  
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Model Specification \dots} \\
\midrule % why "\hline"?!
%\multicolumn{5}{c} {Fitted parameters}\\ \hline
& {Est.} & {St.Err.} & {$t$} & {$p$-val} \\ 
\midrule
\omega_1 & 11.523& 9.6684 & 1.1918 & 1.167e-01      \\
\alpha_1 & 0.009 & 0.0017 & 0.0076 & 4.970e-02$^{**}$ \\
\gamma_1 & 0.932 & 0.5250 & 1.7756 & 3.790e-02$^{**}$ \\
\beta_1  & 0.386 & 0.2238 & 1.7266 & 4.212e-02$^{**}$ \\
\addlinespace
\omega_2 & 1.486 & 0.7199 & 2.0636 & 1.95 e-02$^{**}$ \\
\alpha_2 & 0.001 & 0.0016 & 0.0055 & 4.978e-02$^{**}$ \\
\gamma_2 & 0.323 & 0.2087 & 1.5480 & 6.082e-02$^{***}$\\
\beta_2  & 0.530 & 0.1646 & 3.2172 & 6.472e-04$^{*}$  \\
\bottomrule                  
      
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Model, parameter estimates}
\label{tab:yr3tab2}
    
\medskip\footnotesize
Notes: $^{*}$, $^{**}$, and $^{***}$

\end{table}
\end{document}


Thank you so much...You are awsome..It worked.

@Mico- sorry I was in a hurry. Just did that.

As complementary solution to nice  @Mico's answer (+1). In it are used tabularray and tblr-extras packages:
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, caption, siunitx}
\captionsetup{font={small, sf, stretch=0.8},
              labelfont=bf,
              }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {\lipsum[1][1-2]},    % just to show caption formating
  label = {tab:yr3tab2},
 note{} = {\small
           \begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin={{;\quad }}]
           \item[*] description
           \item[**] description
           \item[***] description
           \end{enumerate*}}
                ]{colspec = {@{}Q[mode=math]
                              Q[c, si={table-format=2.3}]
                              Q[c, si={table-format=1.4}]
                              Q[c, si={table-format=1.4}]
                              Q[c, si={table-format=1.3e-1, tight-spacing,
                                       table-space-text-post = {**}}]                             
                              @{}},
                  row{1-3} = {guard, mode=text},
                  cell{1-2}{1} ={c=5}{},
                  rowsep=0.5pt
                  } 
    \toprule
My model    &           &           &           &                           \\  
Model Specification     
            &           &           &           &                           \\
    \midrule
            &   Est.    &   Std. Error 
                                    & $t$       & $p$-val                   \\ 
    \midrule
\omega_1 & 11.523       & 9.6684    & 1.1918    & 1.167e-01                 \\
\alpha_1 &  0.009       & 0.0017    & 0.0076    & 4.970e-02\TblrNote{**}    \\
\gamma_1 &  0.932       & 0.5250    & 1.7756    & 3.790e-02\TblrNote{**}    \\
\beta_1  &  0.386       & 0.2238    & 1.7266    & 4.212e-02\TblrNote{**}    \\
    \addlinespace
\omega_2 &  1.486       & 0.7199    & 2.0636    & 1.950 e-02\TblrNote{**}    \\
\alpha_2 &  0.001       & 0.0016    & 0.0055    & 4.978e-02\TblrNote{**}    \\
\gamma_2 &  0.323       & 0.2087    & 1.5480    & 6.082e-02\TblrNote{***}   \\
\beta_2  &  0.530       & 0.1646    & 3.2172    & 6.472e-04\TblrNote{*}     \\
    \bottomrule                       
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

![enter image description here

.Thanks...Itw working.
